# What do I need to do to prepare this trunk for painting?

Tags: painting, preparation

I've got this trunk. My eventual goal is to paint it red and use it as a combination storage space and coffee table in my (tiny Manhattan) apartment.

[image: SVN trunk]

It's about fifteen years old. It's covered in a substance that's sort of textured to look faux-leather, but it's very clearly some very plasticky synthetic. It's peeling off on the bottom of the trunk and I can see that the trunk is made of particle board underneath.

The edges (underneath the dots) are another layer of that same faux-leather-y material. The hardware is brass (or more likely some other brass-colored metal). I don't have the patience to cover or paint around all those tiny dots, so I am planning to leave the black-and-brassish trim intact and just paint the flat surfaces red.

The initials on the top of the trunk were done in masking tape fifteen years ago; that torn white thing in the middle is a paper label (like you'd print an address label on), also affixed fifteen years ago.

If I were left to my own devices, here's how I'd go about painting the trunk:

1. Attempt to scrape off masking tape.
2. Get bored and give up on scraping off the masking tape. (You can see that's already happened a few times.)
3. Paint the trunk, masking tape and all.
4. Forget to flip it over, leaving the bottom black-and-raw-particle-board.

This is not the right way to do this.

So what is the right way? What's the best way to get rid of the fifteen-year-old masking tape and sticker? Do I need to prepare the weird pretend leather surface for paint in some way? Or remove it entirely? Bonus points for suggestions of what kind of paint to use; I'm a total DIY noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First you need to remove the masking tape and the label prior to painting, or they will show through on the finished surface. Use [Goo Gone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SRVF0O) or [Goof Off](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045LJZ4M) as BMitch and Tester suggest. (I've never used Goof Off, so I can't vouch for how well it works, but I have firsthand experience on how well Goo Gone works.)
- Next you need to clean the surface, at least with a damp cloth. Let it dry.
- If you really want a clean edge for the parts you're not going to paint, you can use [blue painter's tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z4DU) to mask it off.
- Next, prime the surfaces that you are going to paint. This will help the paint adhere to the trunk and reduce the chance of the paint peeling on down the road.
- Finally, paint. I use latex for most of my projects, since it's easy to clean up. Pay attention to what type of finish you want. A roller will give you a slight orange peel effect, while a brush may leave brush strokes. If you want a smoother finish, you can add some [Floetrol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000C029PM) to latex paint to minimize any brush strokes. Buying a high quality brush can also help. You may have to do several coats of paint, but I'd do a minimum of two.
- If you used painter's tape, carefully pull it up. If you have problems with the paint sticking to the tape, gently score along the edge of the tape with a razor blade.

I wouldn't bother painting the bottom.

Comment: "Priming"? What is this "priming"? Seriously... what do I need to do for that step? I meant it when I said I was a total noob :)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Primer is used to help paint adhere to the surface. Without it, the paint will be uneven, peal off, and do other bad things.

Comment: @BMitch so I just pick up a bucket of primer and slap it on there. Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For the tape and stickers, try a cleaner like Goof Off. Just be sure to test on the bottom to be sure it won't damage the faux-leather.

[image]

Comment: also [goo gone](http://www.googone.com/) works rather well, and has a lemony fresh scent.